# View not taking full width - ConstraintLayout - RecyclerView - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a simple layout for the items in RecyclerView, which contains a TextView and a RadioButton. Here is the layout xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_thali_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="Name"       
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/materialRadioButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/materialRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now when I run the app, the RecyclerView looks like this -

[image]

If I set a fixed width (which I don't want to) for the TextView, then it is showing the TextView content.

I also tested the xml code in a separate layout,

[image]

As you can see it is showing the view as it should. But when using it as an item in RecyclerView, then only the TextView is not showing.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_thali_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="Name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
    android:id="@+id/materialRadioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I removed some extra constraint `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/materialRadioButton"` and added minor changes. This got to work.

Comment: Actually I don't want to set it as wrap_content, because I may want to add a different background to that TextView. But I will accept your answer, as I did not mentioned it in the question.

If anyone having this problem and don't have any problem with setting the view width as wrap content, then this solution will work.

 And if you don't want to set the width as wrap_content or any fixed width, look for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed it. All I had to do is setting the RecyclerView width as match_parent. Previously it was 0dp.